# Type checking of array index value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Javascript if I want to do type checking of an array index I can do something like this:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,"the monster from the green lagoon"]

for (i=0;  i < array.length;  i++) {

    if (typeof(array[i]) === 'number')      {
    console.log("yes these are all numbers");

    }

    else        {
    console.log("Index number " + i + " is " +  array[i] +": No this is not a number");

    }

}
```

In Ruby I don't understand how to do this. I'm trying to type check against Integers. 
I understand that in the Ruby world it's considered good etiquette to use the each method thus basic looping is something like this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array.each { |x| puts x }
```

The part I'm confused about is the syntax is foreign and I'm unclear where the logic goes. I haven't gotten to the actual type checking yet but from what I read it would compare against the **Integer** type thus:

```
if array[i] == Integer
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.all? { |x| x.is_a? Integer }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be most straight forward, and not noisy.

```
array.all? {|x| x.is_a? Numeric}
```

I use Numeric here rather than Integer as your log implies that you are trying to ensure it is a number, not necessarily an Integer.  So this will allow Float, Integer, BigDecimal, etc.

Based on that answer, in general, you could then report it to a log, as a group.

If you want to log individual items, then using `each` or perhaps `each_with_index` is the way to go.

```
 array.each_with_index {|x, i| $LOG.puts "element at #{i} that is #{x.inspect} is not a number" unless x.kind_of? Numeric }
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing `object == Integer`, you are saying `Is my object, the Integer class?` but you want to know if object is an instance of this class, not the class itself.

In Ruby, to test an instance's class you can do

```
Integer === object
object.is_a?(Integer)
object.instance_of?(Integer)
object.kind_of?(Integer) # returns true when object is a subclass of Integer too !
object.class == Integer
```

※ by the way, `2.class => Fixnum`.
You can see your objects' class with

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array.each { |x| puts x.class }
```